# jQuery change() get data-i attribute for the selected option

Tags: jquery

I have a select box and when it change() I want to get the selected option "data-i" attribute

The HTML:

```
<select id="end-select" name="end-select">
    <option value="24h" data-i="24h">24 Hours</option>
    <option value="3d" data-i="3d">3 Days</option>
    <option value="1w" data-i="1w">1 Week</option>
    <option value="1m" data-i="1m" selected>1 Month</option>
    <option value="st" data-i="st">Specific Time</option>
</select>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('select#end-select').change(function() {

    $data_i = /* the data-i attribute of the selected option */;

    alert($data_i);

});
```

Then to use this for dependent select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside the change handler refers to the changed `select` element, so you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and the [selected filter](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to find the selected option and then use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get the data value

```
$('select#end-select').change(function() {

    var $data_i = $(this).find(':selected').data('i')

    alert($data_i);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify 'select' since you are using an ID.

You can use `.attr("attribute-name")` method or `.data('data-name')` (no need to write data)

And you can use `var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);` to find selected option